# How can I get an average from json values using angular and firebase

Tags: json, angular, firebase

first of all, I'm French so all my apologies for my english...

I would like to calculate an average from values in json using firebase and angular. My goal is to filter with a specific id and get the rate value.

```
"avis" : {
"-LTMQXqMDrRPgJmtYteU" : {
  "date" : "11/11/2018",
  "description" : "jkldjflsdjfklsdjklfjkdkl",
  "id" : "-LPzmMTwf8muvAl8xhPM",
  "name" : "daniel",
  "rate" : "4"
},
"-LTM_fI6KREHqKkdcjc1" : {
  "date" : "12/12/2018",
  "description" : "jlkj",
  "id" : "-LPzmr9M6DrSCViNphj-",
  "name" : "sfgf",
  "rate" : 2
},
"-LWQJuqDJoogUcZt5KPL" : {
  "date" : "17/01/2019",
  "description" : "FFFF",
  "id" : "-LPzmr9M6DrSCViNphj-",
  "name" : "FFF",
  "rate" : 1
},
```

...
For example, just below, I would like to calculate the rate average for id -LPzmr9M6DrSCViNphj-. So I get rate 2 and 1, the average is 1.5.

I create a function :

```
    this.afDb.list('/avis', ref => ref.orderByChild('id').equalTo(this.item.key)).valueChanges().
subscribe(
  result => {
    console.log('result: ', result);
  });
```

But when I do that, I have all values and I would like only rate values...

I don't know if it is clear...

Thank you very much for your support !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.map()` & `reduce()` to achieve your avg value.

```
let listData = this.afDb.list('/avis', {
            query: {
                orderByChild: 'id',
                equalTo: this.item.key,
            }
        }).valueChanges();

let avg = listData.map(res => res["rate"]).reduce((a, b) => a + b)/listData.length;
```

Or with the same code you can use like below code to get average.

```
this.afDb.list('/avis', ref => ref.orderByChild('id').equalTo(this.item.key)).valueChanges().
subscribe(
  result => {

    console.log('result: ', result);
    let avg = result.map(res => res. rate).reduce((a, b) => a + b)/result.length;

  });
```

By `.map()` & `.reduce()` you will get your total rating and then divide it with array `length`.

Ref Link : https://www.jstips.co/en/javascript/array-average-and-median/

Hope this will helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I try your code, I have an error : Argument of type '{ query: { orderByChild: string; equalTo: any; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QueryFn'.Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'query' does not exist in type 'QueryFn'.

Comment: That is related to code structure pls update your firebase fetch code as per your lib version.

Comment: I try something, please see my new question. Thank you !

Comment: No... I post a new question for you :-) @CodeChanger in this page.

Comment: ok check my updated answer may be that will help you to get average from result array.

Comment: I already try your answer but I have an error. rate in "res => res.rate" doesn't exist...

Comment: ok so try like this `res => res["rate"]` and tell me is it working or not ?

Comment: Oh my god ! It's works !!!!!!!! Thank you very much !!!!! Actually it's works with res => res['rate'] but thank you !!!

Comment: at finally it works. Great (y) please accept this answer so other can find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
const total = avis.reduce((sum, item) => sum + item.rate, 0);

console.log(total);
```

**OR**

```
this.http.get('/avis')
.map(response.avis)
.map(res => res.rate)
.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
.subscribe(res => console.log(res))
```

Comment: this will take the value from the json and add all those values and print a result

Answer (score 0):

@CodeChanger :

```
this.listData = this.afDb.list('avis', ref => ref.orderByChild('id').equalTo(this.item.key)).valueChanges();
this.avg = this.listData.map(res => res.rate).reduce((a, b) => a + b) / this.listData.length;
```

There is no error after the compilation but when I launch my app, I have this error:

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.listData.map is not a function

Comment: Please use comment section not add your comment as answer of this question.